# how to write a object of type MediaItem to type book

Tags: java, compiler-errors

i havent acutally started coding this yet but i didnt know how to do this yet and wanted to resolve before i actually put time into this.

the basic setup is i have 4 classes, one class called MediaItem and then three other classes that extend Mediaitem called Book, VideoRecord, AudioRecord.
each of which will have get and set methods for these variables
callNumber
copyNumber
borrower
GregorianCalender

now lets say i have a array of MediaItems which contains Books, VideoRecord, AudioRecords objects but is considered by the array as a MediaItem
now assume that array MediaItem has 3 copys of each object on it

my question is this, method I wish to write but cannot figure out how to properly assign this

```
/**
     * Renews all books checked out to the given borrower.
     * 
     * @param borrower the borrower
     * @param currentDate the date the renewal was requested
     * @return an array containing the books that were renewed
     */
public Book[] renew(String borrower, GregorianCalendar currentDate){}
```

assume i have already used a for Loop and implemented a if statement such as

```
items[i].getBorrower.equals(borrower){}
```

as in the method i wish to return a array of Books specifically but of course the error is this

```
public final int MAX_ITEMS = 500;
Books[] book = new Book[MAX_ITEMS];
//forloop here
for( int i = 0; i < MediaItem.length; ++i){}
if (MediaItem[i].getBorrower.equals(borrower))
{
// args to add to date here
// the problem below
   book[i] = MediaItem[i];
}
return book;
}
```

i will run a incompatible types error because i cannot assign a MediaItem to Book object
how can i resolve this as the goal is the return a array of books

forgive bugs I just typed this up as example for a problem but it should let you get the gist of it
so

```
// find and match borrower of object in MediaItem array (completed)
// add 14 days using GregorianCalender (completed)
// assign MediaItem to type book and return array(error)
```

Comment: Does it need to be in an array? Why not use List?

Comment: i think i figured out what i need to do but i dont know how to put it into code, first yes i want it to remain as a array, and does anyone know how to downcast? or was it upcast?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Java's Generics but you may need to use a List instead of Array since you cannot create arrays of generics in Java.

```
class Book extends Media {}

class Media {
    String borrower;
}


class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Media> media = new ArrayList<>();
        media.add(new Media());
        media.add(new Book());
        for (Media medium : media) {
            System.out.println(medium.borrower);
        }
    }
}
```